# How to write trycatch for this scenario in R

Tags: r, try-catch

Currently I have written the ifelse statement to get the correct symbol pattern. But I want to know how I can write tryCatch for this statement? Because sometimes getSymbols returns error if symbol doesn't have correct extension.

```
getSymbols(
  
  ifelse(
    substring(stocksList[i,1],1,1) == "^" | grepl(".BO", stocksList[i,1]),
    stocksList[i,1] , 
    paste0(stocksList[i,1], ".NS") 
  ),
  
  from = fromDate, 
  to = toDate,
  periodicity = freqStr ,
  return.class = 'zoo',
  env = NULL
)
```

Comment: Is `stocksList` a data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the complete code inside `tryCatch` ?

```
tryCatch({
  getSymbols(ifelse(
    substring(stocksList[i,1],1,1) == "^" |   grepl(".BO", stocksList[i,1]),
    stocksList[i,1] , 
    paste0(stocksList[i,1] , ".NS") 
  ),
  from = fromDate, 
  to = toDate,
  periodicity = freqStr ,
  return.class = 'zoo',
  env = NULL)
  }, 
  error = function(e) message('Cannot download the data')
)
```

Comment: I want to run other snippet of code if there is error during first getsymbols

Comment: Can you please update your post to include what you want to do? I wrote an answer for the question you asked in your main post.

Comment: You can run the snippet of code in `error` part of `tryCatch`.